# Simple ESP32 MCP2515 CAN code to VP230

Tags: esp32, can-bus

I have a working code that uses MCP2515 CAN module. Wanted to minimize the size of required modules, so I went with VP230 CAN transceiver and I'm having trouble relaying the same data through different libraries. All it has to do is log in with the first ''payload1'' and send voltage instruction with ''setdefaultvolt''. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**MCP2515** code:

```
#include <mcp_can.h>
#include <mcp_can_dfs.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>

//pins:
#define CAN_INT 17                                                                         // Set INT to pin 2
MCP_CAN CAN(5);                                                                         // Set CS to pin 4 (D2)

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);
  pinMode(17, INPUT);                                                                       //Setting pin 2 for /INT input

START_INIT:
  if(CAN_OK == CAN.begin(MCP_ANY, CAN_125KBPS, MCP_8MHZ))
  {
  }
  else
  {
    delay(100);
    goto START_INIT;
  }
  CAN.setMode(MCP_NORMAL);                                                        //set operation mode to normal so the MCP2515 sends acks to received data.
  unsigned char payload1[8] = {0x16, 0x50, 0x71, 0x07, 0x97, 0x089, 0x00, 0x00};  //login data with serial number
  CAN.sendMsgBuf(0x05004804, 1, 8, payload1);                                     //send login data

  unsigned char setdefaultvolt[5] = {0x29, 0x15, 0x00, 0xFE, 0x10};              //this is the command for setting the default output voltage (Last two bytes, LSB first). 16 80 is the maximum voltage of 57.6 V
  CAN.sendMsgBuf(0x05019C00, 1, 5, setdefaultvolt);                              //send setup data
}

void loop()
{
}
```

**VP230** code:

```
#include <CAN_config.h>
#include <ESP32CAN.h>

CAN_device_t CAN_cfg;

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  CAN_cfg.speed=CAN_SPEED_1000KBPS;
  CAN_cfg.tx_pin_id = GPIO_NUM_19;
  CAN_cfg.rx_pin_id = GPIO_NUM_23;

  CAN_frame_t my_frame;
  CAN_frame_t my_frame2;

  ESP32Can.CANInit();

  my_frame.FIR.B.FF = CAN_frame_ext;
  my_frame.MsgID = 0x05004804;
  my_frame.FIR.B.DLC = 8;

  my_frame.data = {0x16, 0x50, 0x71, 0x07, 0x97, 0x089, 0x00, 0x00};

  ESP32Can.CANWriteFrame(&my_frame);

  my_frame.FIR.B.FF = CAN_frame_ext;
  my_frame.MsgID = 0x05019C00;
  my_frame.FIR.B.DLC = 5;

  my_frame2.data = {0x29, 0x15, 0x00, 0xFE, 0x10};

  ESP32Can.CANWriteFrame(&my_frame2);

}

void loop()
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just spotted this, but if any one else finds it: You have one CAN speed set to 125kb on MCP2515 the other to 100kb on the VP230.

That's why you won't get anything!

Mark

Answer (score 1):

from datasheet ...CAN controller at speeds up to 1 Mbps.

On the SN65HVD230 and SN65HVD231, pin 8 provides three different modes of operation: high-speed, slope
control, and low-power modes. The high-speed mode of operation is selected by connecting pin 8 to ground,
allowing the transmitter output transistors to switch on and off as fast as possible with no limitation on the rise
and fall slopes.